# Is Firebase appropriate for hard real-time computation?

Tags: real-time, firebase, hard-real-time, soft-real-time

I recently came across Firebase and found it very interesting.

Having read up on the [differences between hard real-time and soft real-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17308956/differences-between-hard-real-time-soft-real-time-and-firm-real-time), I am now curious as to whether Firebase is appropriate for hard real-time computation or not.

My intuition is that it would only really be good for soft real-time, but I have come across little (other than its nature as SaaS) to truly validate this feeling.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking about it more - network speed is an obvious problem, potentially causing seconds worth of delays. That would hardly qualify as hard real-time.